# Did not one single person vote in the 2020 Moderator Election?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, election, statistics

The Pets 2020 Community Moderator Election page found on Pets Meta states this:

[image]

> 1,167 voters were eligible, 0 visited the site during the election, 71 visited the election page, and 0 voted

Is this a glitch or typo? Or is it related to the fact that since there were only two nominees, voting was unnecessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not a glitch nor a typo, it is like this because:

- there were 2 open positions and 2 candidates;
- this is a beta site, so in such a case candidates are simply appointed unless the nominations had to be invalidated for some reason.

On the other hand, on graduated sites elections are cancelled if there are less candidates than open positions.

All relevant information about this process could be found [in this post](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2316).

I would like to use this occasion to express my appreciation and gratitude to all the 0 people who have voted for me; thank you so much, you are truly amazing! :3

Answer (score 4):

This is neither a glitch nor a typo. It's the way elections are run on StackExchange. Since there were just as many nominees as open positions, the actual voting was skipped and all nominees became moderators. Voting wouldn't have changed the result in any way.